# PHP--create file for download

Tags: php, export

I am creating a text file for download in PHP, but it always has a bunch of numeral 1s at the end, e.g. 1111111111111111111111 
It happens whether I flush the buffer or not. The output itself is fine. It just has this extraneous junk at the end. Any clues?

```
function exportMyOrders() {
    $output = $this->getMyOutput();

    // Push the report.
    $today = getdate();
    $today_str = $today['year'].'-'.$today['mon'].'-'.$today['mday'];
    $export_file = 'MyFileName_'.$today_str.'.txt';
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($export_file));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    //      flush();

    print $output;
    die();
}
```

Comment: At the end of the $output, or at the end of the file ?

Comment: I don't think setting three Content-Type headers is doing anything useful; could you also add the code for `getMyOutput`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AHA! I found it. In the function creating the output I had the following:

```
$output .= print($next_order);
```

No idea why I did that. Corrected it with a simple:

```
$output .= $next_order;
```

DUH!